# How to Extend localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am using the localStorage in this demo here,

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/exp/exp_webstorage.html

Basically it is a mapping application which caches map tiles in the localStorage.

I quite quickly reach the 5MB limit and from then onwards I get errors, QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR.

How can I extend the localStorage? Or what other options do I have to store data on the client side in HTML5, has anybody used the indexdDB, does it work in chrome?

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

And of course the web database specification has been deprecated so I would like to avoid that,

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Comment: You could just cache in memory instead? That is, keep all data referenced from JavaScript. Unless you need data to stay persistent LocalStorage seems overkill to me

Comment: I am looking into a solution which will work on mobile devices which could be offline, so persistence would be required if a user plans to go offline.

Comment: You could consider using the HTML5 application cache - we have had some success with offline mobile applications by listing each map tile in the manifest file.  The way it updates isn't ideal however for a large number of tiles so we are now switching to storing the tiles in IndexedDB instead which can allow us to fully control the sync/update process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the **user** can extend localstorage but the website can't (by design). You simply need to catch the error in Javascript and show the user a dialog requesting they increase their storage limit - preferably providing some instructions for major browsers.

EDIT: Perhaps not so simple. It seems some browsers don't allow the user to increase the storage size. [Google seems convinced the localStorage API doesn't scale well to large files and developers should consider IndexedDB instead](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985).